# Using Puppet to install, initdb and start Postgres database

Tags: database, virtual-machines, postgresql, puppet

We are trying to write a Puppet to provision the Virtual Machine.  One of the tasks is to install and populate Postgres database with data.

We can decompose this task into a few smaller tasks:

1. install
2. initdb
3. start
4. populate database with data (pg_dump from production database)

It seems Puppet will be responsible for Step 1: install.

Should we use Puppet to perform Step 2, 3, 4 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern when using puppet is managing the installation, configuration and service status of a package. You last step can also be achieved as long as you ensure idempotency. A (very) simple skeleton for this kind of task:

```
class foo (
  $some_param_in_hiera,
  ){

  package {
    'foo_pkg':
      ensure => installed,
  }

  service {
    'foo_svc':
      ensure    => running,
      enable    => true,
      hasstatus => true,
      require   => Package['foo_pkg'];
  }

  file {
    '/etc/foo/some.conf':
      mode    => '0644',
      owner   => root,
      group   => root,
      source  => 'puppet:///modules/foo/some.conf',
      #content => template('foo/some.conf.erb'),
      require => Package['foo_pkg'],
      notify  => Service['foo_svc'];
  }

  exec {
    'some_task':
      command     => 'echo 'foo bar baz'',
      refreshonly => true,
      creates     => '/some/file/to/ensure/idempotency'
  }
}
```

Also, check the [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com) for already existing code that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The first three steps are definitely within Puppet's realm.  Installation is a `package` resource, initdb can be done with `exec` if the package doesn't do it itself, and starting the service is a `service` resource.

But populating the database is probably not a good use of Puppet.  You could probably do it with a lot of custom code (e.g, a separate resource type for a table, a function, etc.), but it would be a lot of work and somewhat unchartered territory.  I suggest you look for a different way to do that.

Comment: Some reading on this: http://www.pgcon.org/2013/schedule/events/540.en.html